# conditional check inside a foreach is causing errors

Tags: php, screen-scraping, simple-html-dom

I am using `Simple_html_dom` trying to grab `Reputation points` and make a check on those values and then  extract only those user profiles whose `Repu` is greater that `200`. Below is the code, It works fine when doing this

`

```
$html2=str_get_html($html1);
foreach ($html2->find('.user-details') as $value) {

        foreach($html2->find('.reputation-score') as $repu){


                echo (int)$repu->plaintext.$value.'<br>';

        }
        }
```

`When doing the above i am getting all the`reputation and the user details`well each line, looks fine till now. But now i wanna perform a`conditional check`and then echo only those profiles whose repo is higher than`100`. So when i am trying the below code

`

```
$html2=str_get_html($html1);

foreach ($html2->find('.user-details') as $value) {

        foreach($html2->find('.reputation-score') as $repu){

                if($repu>100)
                {
                echo ($repu->plaintext.$value.'<br>';
            }
        }
        }
```

I am getting an error saying **Object of class simple_html_dom_node could not be converted to int**  seeing that i've tried doing `(int)` to convert and then echo still couldnt solve

Any help here ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP String to Int Conversion Losing Value (using simple\_html\_dom)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20794506/php-string-to-int-conversion-losing-value-using-simple-html-dom)

Comment: What exactly did you try with int, did you try `(int)$repu->plaintext` ?

Comment: Yes i did that! still got the same error! .

Comment: ok, I thought you only tried `(int)$repu`. You should be more specific.

Comment: to be more specific this is what i've tried `foreach($html2->find('.reputation-score') as $repu){
$rep=(int)$repu->plaintext;
                if($rep>100)
                {
                echo $value.'<br>';
            }
        }`

Comment: You're iterating the same thing inside as you are outside. Something wrong there.